# Mailgun is emails to a specific domain are failing

Tags: mailgun

I'm configuring a Mailgun account with a website we've had developed. When testing the emailing functionality from the site, everything works as expected with multiple email domains (Gmail and some others), but there is one domain I tested that doesn't work at all: umich.edu. I can see the logs on the Mailgun site, and the email is accepted, but then fails saying `Unknown host`.

The site dev team has set up a handle for Mailgun, and I put in the API key and mailgun domain. We are using Gandi.net for site hosting. I copied the DNS records into the Gandi DNS file (2 TXT records, 2 MX records, and a CNAME record). The only other potential symptom I've seen is that the MX records don't validate on the Mailgun site, and I'm not sure why.

Here is the DNS records file on Gandi:

```
@ 10800 IN SOA ns1.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net. 1537064952 10800 3600 604800 10800
* 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN A <IP ADDRESS>
@ 10800 IN MX 10 mxa.mailgun.org.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 mxb.mailgun.org.
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"
email.mg 1800 IN CNAME mailgun.org.
mg 1800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
smtp._domainkey.mg 1800 IN TXT "k=rsa; p=..."
```

I removed the domain key and the IP address since this site is still in development but on a public server for final testing.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me? Many thanks!
Buggaby

Update:
From a few other searches and some back-and-forth with Mailgun support, it looks like the reason is that umich does sender address verification. I'm not sure how to counter this, but I [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923561/mailgun-server-response-550-sender-rejected) SO question says the solution is to add the subdomain to the MX records, too. So I removed the mailgun MX records, since I'm using Gandi to handle email forwarding, and doubled up the Gandi mx records with ones that include the mg subdomain as well.

```
@ 10800 IN SOA ns1.gandi.net. hostmaster.gandi.net. 1537392904 10800 3600 604800 10800
* 10800 IN CNAME webredir.vip.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN A <IP Address>
@ 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
@ 10800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:_mailcust.gandi.net ?all"
email.mg 1800 IN CNAME mailgun.org.
mg 10800 IN MX 10 spool.mail.gandi.net.
mg 10800 IN MX 50 fb.mail.gandi.net.
mg 1800 IN TXT "v=spf1 include:mailgun.org ~all"
smtp._domainkey.mg 1800 IN TXT "k=rsa; p=..."
```

That hasn't solved it so far, though. It's been 16 hours since I made the change and it still isn't working.

Could it be something with the spf records?

Comment: If emails to all other domains work, then maybe there are / were some problems with dns servers for umich.edu (I just checked it and at the beginning whois couldn't locate it, now it seems to work though) - if that's the case and after a while emails still won't be delivered to this particular domain then creating a support ticket in mailgun might help. As per the MX records: I think you should configure mailgun ones for the mg subdomain (as already done with txt and cname) instead of main one as in you're sample record as you already have MX pointing somewhere else for the main domain

Comment: I posed a question to Mailgun support and they replied by saying that some servers check the MX records for consistency. Even though the Mailgun site says that MX records are only required when you're receiving email, apparently some servers make this required for sending as well. Now to figure out why the MX records aren't working. Will update if this is the problem.

Comment: They could just be rejecting your email as junk... You might have already been blacklisted

Comment: You might need to setup DKIM,DMARC and SPF... https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/04/15/spf-dkim-and-dmarc-brief-explanation

Comment: Isn't DKIM the same as smtp? The Mailgun control panel has this option `DKIM Selector: smtp` and there is an smtp txt item with a key in the DNS records file.

Comment: I've also reached out to Umich to find out if we've been blacklisted. Thanks.